# How do I loop through JSON with jQuery?

Tags: jquery, json

I've seen a lot of sites about this topic, but I can't get any of the examples and instructions to work for me.

I want to loop through some JSON using jQuery. In the JSON example below I'd like to output "model-1" and then output just the "origin". Once that is done then I would do the same thing for the next entry which in this case is "model-2". This could go on hundreds of times until it is finished so I can't specifically call of the entries ("model-1", "model-2", "model-3", etc.) by name.

```
{
    "model-1": {
        "origin": "Japan",
        "price": "$149",
        "availability": "Available"
    },
    "model-2": {
        "origin": "USA",
        "price": "$199",
        "availability": "Available"
    }
}
```

And here is the code I have so far to do this.

```
jQuery(function($) {
    $.getJSON('/mydata.json', function(data) {

      var obj = jQuery.parseJSON(data);

    });
});
```

I would add more extensive code including my loop, but literally nothing I've tried has given me good results. Either I get nothing and it breaks or I get a bunch of 'undefined's. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need to parse the JSON. That is only needed if you specifically fetch is as text (using the `ajax` method and setting the `dataType` property), or use automatic detection (using the `ajax` method without setting the `dataType` property) and the server returns it with the wrong MIME type. The `getJSON` method is a wrapper for the `ajax` method, with the `dataType` set to JSON, so it will automatically parse the response.

The callback function will be called with a parameter containing the response already parsed into an object, so you can loop through it. Example:

```
$.getJSON('/mydata.json', function(data) {
  $.each(data, function(key, obj){
    console.log(key + ' has origin ' + obj.origin);
  });
});
```

Note that the order of the properties in the object is unspecified. The code above will actually show the items in different order depending on what browser is used.

Comment: Thank you for touching on the parsing thing. Once I removed that from my code things started to actually DO something. I am curious about the items appearing in a different order depending on browser. I am using the latest IE, Firefox, and Chrome and all three of them displayed the results in the order I expected. Which is to say, the order they appear in the JSON file. Which browsers would display them out of order? And what could I do to prevent that?

Comment: @jimmykup: Any browser might give you the items in any order, depending on the situation. It seems that you found a case where the browsers behave the same, probably because the property names are similar, but that may change when you get to `model-10` for example. It's not just that the order is unspecified, I have actually observed browsers returning the properties in different order, so even if you seem to get a consistent result there are differences in the implementation in different browsers.

Answer (score 1):

Just use a **for...in** loop, and loop through the `obj`

```
$.getJSON('/mydata.json', function(data) {

  var obj = jQuery.parseJSON(data);
  for(j in obj)
    {
     console.log(obj[j].origin);
    }

});
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `$.each` to iterate over the models:

```
$.each(data, function(model, value) {
    var origin = value.origin;
    // use model and origin
});
```

However the models will not be in the original order, as Javascript object properties do not preserve the order when loaded from JSON. If you need to preserve the order, you'd have to have an array on the top level:

```
[
    {
        "model": "model-1",
        "origin": "Japan",
        "price": "$149",
        "availability": "Available"
    },
    {
        "model": "model-2"
        "origin": "USA",
        "price": "$199",
        "availability": "Available"
    }
]
```

Which again you could iterate with `$.each`:

```
$.each(data, function (index, item) {
    var model = item.model,
        origin = item.origin;
    // do whatever you need with model and origin
});
```

(Also `$.getJSON` already supplies a parsed structure into your function, so you do not need to do `JSON.parse`/`$.parseJSON` there).

Answer (score 0):

Use .each

A generic iterator function, which can be used to seamlessly iterate over both objects and arrays

http://api.jquery.com/jquery.each/

http://www.mkyong.com/jquery/jquery-loop-over-json-string-each-example/

Answer (score 0):

The `for (... in ...)` loop structure would be ideal here. Here's what it would look like:

```
$.getJSON('/mydata.json', function(data) {
    var obj = jQuery.parseJSON(data);

    for (var prop in obj) {
        console.log(obj[prop].origin);
    }
});
```

When you use the `for (... in ...)` structure, you loop through the keys of all the properties on the specified object. `prop` will be first "model-1", and then "model-2", and so on so forth. So you access the property at that key, and from there you can get `origin`.